# Can't change destination of symbolic link

Tags: command-line, symbolic-link

I want to change the destination of an existing symbolic link, without removing the link or the old destination.

I have previously created a symbolic link to a directory such as follows :

```
$ cd /usr/lib/jvm/

$ ls -lh
drwxr-xr-x 8 uucp  143 4.0K Sep 10 20:22  jdk1.7.0_04
drwxr-xr-x 8 uucp  143 4.0K Aug 29 05:42  jdk1.7.0_07

$ sudo ln -s jdk1.7.0_04 oracle-jdk-7

$ ls -lh
drwxr-xr-x 8 uucp  143 4.0K Sep 10 20:22  jdk1.7.0_04
drwxr-xr-x 8 uucp  143 4.0K Aug 29 05:42  jdk1.7.0_07
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   12 May 11 11:27  oracle-jdk-7 -> jdk1.7.0_04/
```

Now I want to change this, to link to the other directory :

```
$ sudo ln --force -s jdk1.7.0_07 oracle-jdk-7
```

But it doesn't work without any errors :

```
$ ls -lh
drwxr-xr-x 8 uucp  143 4.0K Sep 10 20:36  jdk1.7.0_04
drwxr-xr-x 8 uucp  143 4.0K Aug 29 05:42  jdk1.7.0_07
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   12 May 11 11:27  oracle-jdk-7 -> jdk1.7.0_04/
```

Any help ?

Comment: Maybe this is a small detail, but it looks like the actual command you ran is `sudo ln -s jdk1.7.0_04/ oracle-jdk-7`. Note the slash after `04`.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

To create a symbolic link to a *directory*, use the 'n' option:

```
ln -sfn DESTINATION_DIRECTORY LINK_NAME
```

- `DESTINATION_DIRECTORY` is the name of the link target;
- `LINK_NAME` is the name of the link.
- The `f` option means to replace the existing link (ie, delete it first).

The `n` option is a bit complicated.  I believe your command may have created a link to `jdk1.7.0_07` inside  the directory `jdk1.7.0_04`, via the link `oracle-jdk-7` rather than replacing the link. If so, you should delete the link to avoid confusion.

Comment: You could also use option `T`, i.e. `ln -sfT TARGET LINK_NAME`